# How to know what the executed methods are when a specific button is clicked?

Tags: debugging, odoo, odoo-14

I am currently in a situation where I need to find what methods are executed when a specific button is clicked.

I have traced the method that binds to the button but there are too many places that it links to. Is there any way to list all of them; so that I can check them individually?

Right now, I am tracking the code in model but when it comes to the methods that use `depends`, that can't be easily traced.

What makes it so difficult is that the Odoo server here currently has hundreds of customized modules.